# Show that the sample variance of a normal distribution is a consistent estimator of $\sigma^2$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

> Let $ X_{1}, X_{2}, \cdots, X_{n} $ be an independent random sample
> from $ N\left(\mu, \sigma^{2}\right) $.
>
> If $ \mathrm{E}\left(X^{4}\right)=s^{4}+6 s^{2} \sigma^{2}+3 \sigma^{2} $ when $ X \sim N\left(s, \sigma^{2}\right) $, show that
> $S^{2}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}\right)^{2} $ is a
> consistent estimator of $ \sigma^{2}$.

As $S^2$ is asymptotically unbiased, it suffices to show that $\mathrm{Var}\left(S^{2}\right) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. However, I'm only able to use the chi-squared distribution to show $\mathrm{Var}\left(S^{2}\right) \rightarrow 0$. How can I use the condition of $\mathrm{E}\left(X^{4}\right)$ to solve this problem?

Comment: You compute $\operatorname{Var}(S^2)$ using $\mathbb{E}X^i$ for $i=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: I think it's really hard to compute $E[(S^2)^2]$. If you want to show $S^2$ is consistent estimator and you know weak law of large number, you can use it to show that $S^2$ converges to $\sigma^2$ in probability, which implies that $S^2$ is consistent estimator for $\sigma^2$. But for this method, you need to understand what's the meaning of convergence in probability.

Comment: Neither normality nor existence of 4th moment is required for this to hold. Only requirement is the i.i.d condition and $E(X_1^2)<\infty$. Then by the law of large numbers, $$S^2=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2-\overline X^2 \stackrel{P}\to E(X_1^2)-(E(X_1))^2=\operatorname{Var}(X_1)$$